# Как программно нажать сочетание клавиш в другом, неактивном окне?

Tags: c#

простейший пример хотя бы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Импортировать функцию WinAPI PostMessage или SendMessage
2. Узнать дескриптор нужного окна
3. Создать сообщение о посылке клавиш, передав туда дескриптор нужного окна
4. Отправить сообщение окну.

Answer (score 2):

Пример из мсдна для `SendKeys.SendWait`:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Keykey
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            // Get a handle to an application window.
            [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,
                string lpWindowName);

            // Activate an application window.
            [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
            public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // Get a handle to the Calculator application. The window class
                // and window name were obtained using the Spy++ tool.
                IntPtr calculatorHandle = FindWindow("CalcFrame", "Калькулятор");

                // Verify that Calculator is a running process.
                if (calculatorHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Calculator is not running.");
                    return;
                }

                // Make Calculator the foreground application and send it 
                // a set of calculations.
                SetForegroundWindow(calculatorHandle);
                SendKeys.SendWait("111");
                SendKeys.SendWait("*");
                SendKeys.SendWait("11");
                SendKeys.SendWait("=");
            }
        }
    }
```

А через какие функции еще можно отправлять сообщения? Нашел пока:

```
SendKeys.SendWait

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, ulong lParam)

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
054.static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, INPUT [] pInputs, int cbSize);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
```

Почему спрашиваю, через SendKeys.SendWait не передается почему то нужному приложению. Заголовок и класс смотрел через Spy++

**UPD:** разобрался, не работало из-за того, что пример запускал от имени обычного пользователя, а приложение от имени администратора. Будьте внимательны!